# Properties of higher-order partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request

Have any authors looked systematically at the fourth-order equation
$$u_{tt} + \Delta\Delta u = 0$$
in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or on bounded domains? I suppose one could look at it as a Schrodinger system, i.e.
$$i u_t + \Delta u = \bar{v} \qquad iv_t + \Delta v = 0$$
but I'm not sure if this is the best way to look at it.
I'm looking for solutions, conservation laws, maximum principal and other properties.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Have you tried generating a stress tensor for the equation like what is done for the Schrodinger and wave equations?

Comment: "Biharmonic wave equation" yields about 18,000 results on Google Scholar.